# How will I know when my teammates create a new file or make changes using tortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I didn't get any overlay change when my teammates make changes or add a new file to my project.

Should I regularly update my project to keep track with the updates made? Or am I missing any configuration part that shows a new overlay whenever any of my teammates makes a change?

Note: I get red and other overlays correctly whenever I make changes to files.

Comment: Please note that overlays display your **working copy** status. Your working copy is never affected by the repository without prior action from you.

Comment: Hey thanks @Alvaro G. Vicario. Actually, I had used Ecliplse's CVS some years back. In that, after synchronizing, an arrow-mark would appear whenever a new file is added by any member. So I thought, there would be something similar here in TortoiseSVN too.

Comment: Yep, there is: update. CVS and SVN are fairly similar. Most likely, "synchronize" was a feature of your Eclipse plug-in that would update and commit in a row.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: CommitMonitor seems to be a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would need to do periodic updates to get changes from you team members.  The trigger for this could also be one of the folloiwng.

- A notification from the continuous integration when a build containing changes from other team members has been done.
- A post-commit hook in your subversion server which emails all interested parties whenever there is a check-in.

Comment: One more option: [CommitMonitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor.html)